# How to get View set on the alert in it's OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, onclicklistener

My aim is to change the text of a `TextView` when user clicks on it and replace it with player name whic user enters. So I added a `OnClickListener` to it. So on click I prompt a `Dialog` for user input.

```
private void setPlayerName(TextView textView) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setMessage("Enter Player1 Name");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText inputText = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(inputText);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new inputclickListener(textView));

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

Now code for inputclickListener class is as follows

```
class inputclickListener implements android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    TextView textView;

    public inputclickListener(TextView textView){
        this.textView = textView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //String value = inputText.getText().toString();    //Here I need reference to inputtext
        if(value != null && value.length()>0) {
            textView.setText(value);
        }

    }

}
```

As mentioned in the comment of the code in `inputclickListener` class I need the reference to inputText which is an `EditText` view. My question is how can I get that reference given that we have the reference to it's `Dialog`(I think this should be the Views/EditText parent.. correct me if i am wrong)?

Comment: Can't you just add another field to the constructor of `inputclickListener`, just like you did with `textView`?

Comment: Yes I could but it does not sound logical. textView is not a part of the dialog but edit text is.

Answer (score 1):

For this case I would use anonymous class for the listener for faster coding.

```
private void setPlayerName(final TextView textView) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setMessage("Enter Player1 Name");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText inputText = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(inputText);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            final String value = inputText.getText().toString();
            if(value != null && value.length()>0) {
                textView.setText(value);
            }
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: Maybe **final TextView textView** was the part I was missing. Let me try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `TextWatcher` to the `addTextChangedListener` of the `inputText` and pass whatever data you receive on `onTextChanged` to the `inputclickListener` object .